# Bard token is not working how supposed to be how can i fix it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to ask Bard a question and receive an answer, have I installed the necessary module, etc...
but when I ask the question, example of the code:

```
from bardapi import Bard

def PegarResp(assunto):
    input_text = "Answer me, {}".format(assunto)
    bard_output = Bard(token='token').get_answer(input_text)['content']
    print (bard_output)

PegarResp('Who wins a fight batman or superman?')
```

this error occurs:

Exception has occurred: Exception
SNlM0e value not found. Double-check __Secure-1PSID value or pass it as Bard(token='xxxxx')
File "G:\Portifolio\python mostrar\IA.py", line 6, in PegarResp
bard_output = Bard(token='censored').get_answer(input_text)['content']
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "G:\Portifolio\python mostrar\IA.py", line 9, in 
PegarResp('saude e beleza feminina')
Exception: SNlM0e value not found. Double-check __Secure-1PSID value or pass it as Bard(token='xxxxx')

I get the token in the bard page, developer mode, applications, cookie:https://bard.google.com, name:__Secure-1PSID and I get the value

Is my first time doing this.

I want to be able to ask the bard a question and receive and print the answer